# DNS/BIND configuration to resolve *.mail.*.outlook.com subdomains

Tags: centos, dns, bind, named

I'm running BIND 9.3.3rc2 on a CentOS 5 system acting as an SMTP server. Until last week, I haven't had any problems with DNS or name resolution. The only problems I have resolving are with subdomains for Microsoft's Outlook 365 service.

For our customers who are using Outlook 365, Microsoft has changed their MX server configuration from a generic mail.outlook.com domain to example-com.mail.eo.outlook.com where 'example-com' represents their registered domain (they change the dot to a dash). Sometimes 'eo' becomes 'protection' in this scheme. When a customer has an email at one of these subdomains, our SMTP can't resolve the name and the mail goes into the `mailq`.

If I run `dig example.com MX` I get the following as output:

```
::ANSWER SECTION:
example.com    3600  IN  MX  10  example-com.mail.eo.outlook.com
```

So it finds Microsoft's subdomain for this customer, but I can't ping it or the root domain; they both return

```
ping: unknown host example-com.mail.eo.outlook.com
```

However if I dig this domain using Google's DNS server, I do get an IP address:

```
dig example-com.mail.eo.outlook.com @8.8.8.8

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com. 9 IN A 213.199.154.23
example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com. 9 IN A 213.199.154.87
```

I can statically add those entries to /etc/hosts, but this means being reactive. 
How do I need to configure DNS so that these entries will work? If they work for Google they must work for others as well.

Comment: What is the output of the following commands? ```cat /etc/resolv.conf``` & ```dig example.com MX +trace```

Comment: @Dayvo, I found out what the problem was partially. /etc/resolv.conf only had 127.0.0.1 as its nameserver. I don't know why the local DNS records haven't been updated, but I added our ISP's DNS server to nameserver and restarted named.

Comment: 1) Provide the real names if you want help. 2) a record can have a MX resource type attached to it (so that it will handle email reception) but not have an A/AAAA record so that ping or any other tool on it will fail